# Angular generated css breaks child combinator

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

**Scenario :**

- Trying to run some flexbox demo code in angular 6.1.2 (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) here is the specific example (https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/vWEMWw)
- It does not work, after poking around for a bit it looks like the **CSS get modified in a way that the browser does not like**.

**Relevant CSS :**

```
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

This is what I get

```
.wrapper[_ngcontent-c0]    > *[_ngcontent-c0] {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
 }
```

**Working Case :**

```
.wrapper[_ngcontent-c0]    > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to stop angular for doing this?
- Is there something wrong in the CSS I'm using in the demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `:host`, for more reference [Check the component styling guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

```
:host .wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

you can also try using the `/deep/`

```
:host /deep/ .wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

Hey, I found the second type of styling working, [Checkout the stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcdlzm)

Comment: fantastic, that did the trick :)
One thing to note, this has to be in app.component.css, styles.css did not give the desired results. But that is fine :)

Comment: @BasHamer, using component style in their own component makes your app load  faster and light weight. you can analyse the change difference in gtmatrix or chrome light house audit